# Can someone tell me what brand of bike light this is?

Tags: lighting, headlights

It is a USB chargeable light and supports a strobe mode as well as a few different brightness settings.

Thanks very much!

[image: https://i.imgur.com/IMcyoJ4.png]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/IFGyjHp.png]

Comment: Can you take a clearer/sharper picture of the logo?

Comment: These are the only pictures I have of it. (I've since lost it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something in the Serfas E-Lume family, possibly a [Serfas E-Lume 900](https://www.serfas.com/shop/products/lights/usl-900-e-lume-900/).

[image: Serfas E-Lume 900]

Comment: Probably not street legal in some countries.

Comment: @Michael is that true? Can you link to some evidence? Thanks!

Comment: @JoeK: As far as I’m aware at least in Germany and Austria the front light mustn’t flash and mustn’t even have a flash mode (hence why you can’t even buy such lights in German online stores). It also must be designed in a way not to blind oncoming traffic, which rules out all the usual MTB lights with circular light beam. I suspect the E-Lume 900 does have such a dangerous beam pattern.